# Sweet words to use instead of wife

Tags: word-request

Can anyone give me some words to sweeten the word wife?

Especially commonly used words woild be perfect.

Of was thinking of: **wifie**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a wife, I'd say "NO!"  However, why not ask your wife what terms of endearment she prefers? My hubby (there's one for a wife to use) calls me pet names in private (not sharing them with you) and Sweetheart, Darling or Honey in public. When he refers to me to another person who does not already know my name, 'wife' is the word. If they know my name and that I am his wife, then he calls me Willa.

My husband's ex-wife called him something so stupid in public that they would fight over it. I think any name you call your partner has to start by being first -- agreeable to that person.

My father called Mum, 'Woofers', but not usually across a room or outside of our home. She liked it.